# Local Notification Error iOS

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification

when minimizing the application, all is well, but when I try to deploy the boom going on, this error
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

```
-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
        NSDate *alertTime = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:5];
        UIApplication* app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] init];
        UILocalNotification* notifyAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kAllNews]];

        NSError *error = nil;

        NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];

        NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;

        sortArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];

        if (notifyAlarm)
        {

        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"news"])
        {
            newsNew = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"news"]];
        }

        if (newsNew.count > sortArray.count) {

        notifyAlarm.fireDate = alertTime;
        notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        notifyAlarm.repeatInterval = 0;
        notifyAlarm.soundName = @"Glass.aiff";
        notifyAlarm.alertAction = @"Gipoteza";
        notifyAlarm.alertBody = @"Добавлена новая новость";
        [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

First; did you try putting your code in applicationWillResignActive instead?

Why are you getting a reference to UIApplication in your code? You already have that as a parameter to the method...

Try putting breakpoints in your code to see exactly where this error occurs. I would guess it happens on the last line: [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm], and that it happens because your notifyAlarm object for some reason is nil. Use your debugger to step through the code to see if that object does indeed get set.

Also; be aware that your code has a maximum of 5 seconds from deactivation until it becomes suspended. When suspended; no code can run. If, for example, your NSURLConnection request for some reason takes long to respond, your app will be suspended before the code is finished.